# Crear un TRIGGER para insertar un registro en una tabla

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Tengo tres tablas `Detalle_Compra`, `Detalle_Venta` e `Inventario`:

```
CREATE TABLE Detalle_Compra
(
Pedido int,
Producto int,
Cantidad int not null,
Precio int,
foreign key (Producto) references Productos,
foreign key (Pedido) references Pedidos,
Primary key (Pedido, Producto)
)
Go

CREATE TABLE Detalle_Venta
(
FacturaV int,
Producto int,
Cantidad int,
Precio int,
Primary Key (FacturaV, Producto),
foreign key (Producto) references Productos,
foreign key (FacturaV) references Facturas_V,
)
Go

CREATE TABLE Inventario
(
Factura int,
Operacion varchar (6) not null,
Producto int,
cantidad int not null,
Observacion Nvarchar (200),
Foreign key (Factura, Producto) references Detalle_Compra,
Foreign key (Factura, Producto) references Detalle_Venta,
Primary key (Factura, Operacion,Producto)
)
Go
```

Necesito un TRIGGER para que realice un registro en la tabla `Inventario` cuando se realice un registro en la tabla `Detalle_Compra` y/o `Detalle_Venta`.

Ya trate de hacerlo pero este solo me deja hacer un inserción y luego me sale el mensaje:

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK__Inventario__32E0915F". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "Inventario_Erikar", tabla "dbo.Detalle_Compra".

```
CREATE TRIGGER DIS_InventarioVenta ON Detalle_Venta
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @Factura int
DECLARE @Operacion varchar (6)
DECLARE @Producto int
DECLARE @cantidad int

SELECT @Factura = i.FacturaV  FROM Detalle_Venta i;
SELECT @Producto = i.Producto FROM Detalle_Venta i;
SELECT @cantidad = i.Cantidad  FROM Detalle_Venta i;

INSERT INTO inventario (Factura, Operacion,Producto,cantidad,Observacion)
    VALUES (@Factura,'', @Producto,@cantidad,'')
GO
```

Comment: Excelnte compañeros, tengo un problema en una empresa donde trabajo, hace poco se compro un nuevo servidor y tambien se adquirio un nuevo sistema informatico, lo que es mi problema es que el servidor antiguo tiene un programa hecho a medida y el nuevo sistema que se compro no comtempla muchos de las funciones especiales que contempla el sistema antiguo, los dos servidores entan en la misma red, mi idea es untilizar trigger en en el servidor nuevo especialmente cunado se factura y a travez del trigger insertar directamente los datos de la facturacion en la tabla correspondiente al sistema anter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es simple, estás insertando en `Inventario` una operación que no tiene su contrapartida en `Detalle_Compra`. Además de eso tienes otros errores que dificultan profundizar cualquier análisis, veamos:

En primer lugar: `Foreign key (Factura, Producto) references Detalle_Compra`,   está mal por que no hay ningún campo Factura en `Detalle_Compra` entiendo que en realidad podría llegar a ser así: `Primary key (Pedido, Producto)` (¿o podría ser `FacturaC`?). También en `Foreign key (Factura, Producto) references Detalle_Venta` tienes un problema del mismo tipo, en la tabla `Detalle_Venta` la columna `Factura` la llamas `FacturaV`, por otro lado si eventualmente quisieras las dos FK en inventario, debieras permitir que `factura` o `Pedido` sea "nulleables" cosa que no podrías la PK así: `Primary key (Factura, Operacion, Producto)`. Me imagino que estos son todos errores tipográficos, te sugiero que revises esto y edites la pregunta ya que se dificulta entender el modelo con estas fallas.

Mas allá de lo comentado, una posibilidad es definir `Inventario` de la siguiente forma

```
CREATE TABLE Inventario
(
    Pedido int null,
    Factura int null,
    Operacion varchar (6) not null,
    Producto int,
    cantidad int not null,
    Observacion Nvarchar (200),
    Foreign key (Pedido, Producto) references Detalle_Compra,
    Foreign key (Factura, Producto) references Detalle_Venta,
    -- Primary key (Factura, Operacion,Producto)
)
Go
```

Cambios:

- Agregamos `Pedido` a la tabla (Referencia a compras)
- Hicimos que `Pedido` y `Factura` sean "nulleables", tiene que ser así por que entiendo que o bien insertas desde una compra o desde una venta, es decir o tendremos `Factura` o `Pedido` pero nunca ambos al mismo tiempo.
- Al hacer "nulleables" estos campos tuvimos que comentar la Primary Key, debieras buscar otras columnas para hacer la `PK` por ejemplo agregar una columna `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me servio mucho tu ayuda ya pude solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo intentaria primero es cambiar los select para obtener los datos recien insertados :

```
SELECT @Factura = i.FacturaV, @Producto = i.Producto, @cantidad = i.Cantidad  FROM inserted i;
```

Aunque en realidad el problema es que estas intentando insertar un producto o pedido inexistente en detalle_compra, pero el motivo puede ser el hecho de que la asignacion de las variables la estas haciendo directamente contra la tabla y no contra el registro recién insertado, lo que puede dar resultados inesperados.